# Angular - How to Subscribe Data from Component to Component

Tags: angular, rxjs

[image]I am trying to subscribe a data from a component.
Somehow it's not working now, hope anyone can find out why...

**app.component.html**

```
<app-sample1></app-sample1>
<p></p>
<app-sample2></app-sample2>
```

**sample1.component.html**

```
<div class="main">
    <p>Sample1 !</p>
    Subsribed Title from Sample 2:
    <h3> {{titleFromSample2}}</h3>
</div>
```

**sample2.component.html**

```
<div class="main">
    <p>Sample2 !</p>
    <input type="text" #title (input)="change(title.value)">
</div>
```

**sample.service.ts / sample1.component.ts / sample2.component.ts**

[image]

When text value inserted in Sample2 Input box, 
'change' method in sample2.componet.ts implements fine.

but titleFromSample2 values of sample1.component.ts and sample1.component.html are not changing.

I can't find what wrong is....

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the guide on component interaction: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction ? It has some recipes for different communication strategies and would be a great place to start. Also you haven’t shown how titleFromSample2 is set or provided to component 1.

Comment: well.. I checked the link and Angular official documents, but Cannot find a case that matches as mine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are returning an `Observable` from `getTitle` which is **unicast** by nature. What that would mean is, it won't react to changes in the value of the `title` property in the `SampleService`.

To make it **multicast**, you'll have to use a `Subject` or a `BehaviorSubject` instead.

Something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class SampleService {

  private title: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

  constructor() { }

  setTitle(value: string) {
    this.title.next(value);
  }

  getTitle(): Observable<string> {
    return this.title.asObservable();
  }

}
```

Also since this is going to emit multiple values over time and it's not really recommended to `subscribe` to `Observable`s when they are emitting multiple values over time, you should be using the `async` pipe in the template instead.

So your Component would look like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SampleService } from '../sample.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample1',
  templateUrl: './sample1.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample1.component.css']
})
export class Sample1Component implements OnInit {

  titleFromSample2$: Observable<string>;

  constructor(private sampleService: SampleService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.titleFromSample2$ = this.sampleService.getTitle();
  }

}
```

And then in the template:

```
<div class="main">
    <p>Sample1 !</p>
    Subsribed Title from Sample 2:
    <h3> {{titleFromSample2$ | async}}</h3>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ho8juh) for your ref.

Comment: Thank you!! All you explained are very clear and understandable. Code works like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the SampleService stores the title value but it does't emit new values. Change `title`to `title = new BehaviorSubject('');`

Then in setTitle:

```
setTitle(value: string) {
  this.title.next(value);
}
```

That should do it.